# KendoUI ActionSheet in Angular Called From NavBar Button - Invalid OwnerDocument

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

The following HTML results in error:  Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference, when you set your browser to emulate a tablet such as an IPad.

Codepen is here

http://codepen.io/jcbowyer/pen/wGrLmE

[image: Angular Error]

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kendo UI Mobile Loves AngularJS</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
  <!-- the application CSS file -->
  <link rel="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/mobile/apps/sushi/css/style.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body kendo-mobile-application ng-app="sushiMobileApp">

  <kendo-mobile-view id="index">
    <kendo-mobile-header>
      <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
        Home View
        <button kendo-mobile-button k-align="'right'" data-icon="'contacts'" id="btnProfile" k-on-click="mnuProfile.open($('#btnProfile'))"></button>
      </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
    <ul kendo-mobile-action-sheet="mnuProfile" k-on-command="onCommand(kendoEvent)" k-type="'auto'">
      <li><a href="#" data-command="login">Login</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="(authentication.token.length == 0)"><a href="#" data-command="logout">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-command="showProfile">My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </kendo-mobile-view>

  <script>
    angular.module('sushiMobileApp', [ 'kendo.directives' ]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get this work with k-rel insteal of open.

Updated code is below

Codepen here

http://codepen.io/jcbowyer/pen/KzyQwa

```html
<html>
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kendo UI Mobile Loves AngularJS</title>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
  <!-- the application CSS file -->
  <link rel="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/mobile/apps/sushi/css/style.css">
 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body kendo-mobile-application ng-app="sushiMobileApp">
 
  <kendo-mobile-view id="index">
    <kendo-mobile-header>
      <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
        Home View
        <a kendo-mobile-button k-align="'right'" data-icon="'contacts'" id="btnProfile"
                k-rel="'actionsheet'"
                href="#mnuProfile"></a>
      </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
    <ul kendo-mobile-action-sheet="mnuProfile" id="mnuProfile" k-on-command="onCommand(kendoEvent)" k-type="'auto'">
      <li><a href="#" data-command="login">Login</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="(authentication.token.length == 0)"><a href="#" data-command="logout">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-command="showProfile">My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </kendo-mobile-view>
 
  <script>
    angular.module('sushiMobileApp', [ 'kendo.directives' ]);
  </script>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```